# Oracle query to find records in a table that don't exist?

Tags: oracle, merge, exists

This is probably an easy query but I can't seem to write it.

How can I make a query that looks in a table for all records that don't have the following values in the table

So for the following account,  I need to insert into this table
the values

```
Account = Test003
Role    = Owner
Grp     = AO1
```

because this table doesn't have any columns with Role or Grp = to the above

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ACCOUNT          |   ROLE  |    GRP   |
--------------------------------------------------

| Test003          | Overlay |    WAD    |
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you trying to: A) Query all rows that DO NOT have the values Account = Test003, Role = Owner, and Grp     = AO1? Or are you trying to B) Insert those values into the table in question?

Answer (score 1):

To make a MERGE work use the DUAL table to generate a row for the values you're searching for.

```
merge into your_table yt
using ( select 'Test003' as acct
                , 'Owner' as role
                , 'AO1' as grp
        from dual ) q
  on (yt.account = q.acct
  and yt.role = q.role
  and yt.grp = q.grp)
when not matched then
  insert (account, role, grp)
  values (q.acct, q.role, q.grp)
```

If you want to MERGE multiple records you can use UNION ALL in the USING to create a set of several queries on DUAL.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (account    varchar2(10),
  3     role       varchar2(10),
  4     grp        varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> -- insert sample data
SQL> insert into test
  2    (select 'test001', 'actor'   , 'a01' from dual union  --> contains GRP
  3     select 'test002', 'director', 'd02' from dual union
  4     select 'test003', 'owner'   , 'a01' from dual union  --> contains ROLE and GRP
  5     select 'test004', 'overlay' , 'wad' from dual
  6    );

4 rows created.

SQL>
```

The above sample data mean that I should insert "owner" and "a01" for accounts test002 and test004 as they don't have neither role = owner and grp = a01

```
SQL> insert into test (account, role, grp)
  2    (select x.account, 'owner', 'a01'
  3     from (select account
  4           from test
  5           where role <> 'owner'
  6             and grp <> 'a01'
  7          ) x
  8    );

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test
  2  order by account, role, grp;

ACCOUNT    ROLE       GRP
---------- ---------- ----------
test001    actor      a01
test002    director   d02
test002    owner      a01
test003    owner      a01
test004    overlay    wad
test004    owner      a01

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```